# android screens

Tags: java, android

I want to create an application under ANDROID, but there are many different views. How many screen resolutions for ANDROID devices?

example code:

```
class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

Comment: see this tutorial http://developer.android.com

Comment: see this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html . Dont think too much at the begining. Just follow the tutorials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should go through the design strategies of android devices. [here](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) is the complete set of guidance. And [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html) is the complete guidance for making UI for different screen sizes and densities.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to this [TUTORIAL](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html),it ll help you in creating your first android app.

Enjoy :) Welcome to android world.. :) :) :) :)